# How to use Camera inside of Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there any way to use the Camera inside of an Ionic 2 Application?

There's the ability to install the Cordova plugin but there's no documentation on it for Ionic 2 as far as i know.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of Angular 2 is that now it is using Zones, so people dont have to rewrite stuff in Angular way (like the whole ng-cordova library) because Angular 2 is aware of the stuff that are executed in its context.

To use the camera (or any other cordova plugin) you can go and read the normal cordova documentation https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.getPicture. You can call the getPicture with cameraoptions, 1 is to call the camera, 0 to call the library (already existing photos). The link contains docs for Camera.PictureSourceType : enum.

You can use this plugin in an @Injectable() service and inject it in every component that you need. Also below your "export class" you can "declare var navigator: any" so typescript will not complain.

Here is the whole code that I am using to access camera:
http://prntscr.com/a6xvzq

Comment: That's great to know!

Comment: Shouldn't there be something imported for the app to have access to "camera".navigator?

Comment: when you `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` you have the navigator object available anywhere in the document

Answer (score 0):

Important Get a plugin on:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/

Adn try this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureVideoOptions } from 'ionic-native';


@IonicPage()
@Component({ your component's'
})
export class yourPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PageLoaded');

    //call function camera
    this.GetVideo();
  }
   //Function open camera on View is full loaded.
  public GetVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1 };
    MediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
      (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
      (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
    );

  }
}
```